# Generic representation of PGL(3)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

Let $G$ be the group $PGL(3,F)$, where $F$ is non-archimedean locally compact field, and $(\widetilde{H}_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ the decreasing sequence of open and compact subgroups given by (image in $G$ of following subgroups of $GL(3,F)$) :

$$H_{2n}=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{O}^{\times} & \mathcal{O}  & \mathcal{O} \\ \\
\mathcal{P}  & \mathcal{O}^{\times} & \mathcal{O} \\ \\ 
\mathcal{P}^{n+1} & \mathcal{P}^{n+1} & \mathcal{O}^{\times} \\
\end{pmatrix}~~~~~~\mbox{and}~~~~~~H_{2n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{O}^{\times} & \mathcal{O}  & \mathcal{O} \\ \\
\mathcal{P}  & \mathcal{O}^{\times} & \mathcal{O} \\ \\ 
\mathcal{P}^{n+2} & \mathcal{P}^{n+1} & \mathcal{O}^{\times} \\
\end{pmatrix},$$
where $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ are respectively the ring of integer of $F$ and the the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}$.

Let $(\pi,V)$ be a smooth irreducible generic representation of $G$. We assume that $\pi$ has no non-zero vector fixed by $\widetilde{H}_{0}$ .I'm trying to prove the two following propositions :

1) There exist an integer $n>0$ such that $V^{\widetilde{H}_{n}}\neq0$.

2) Let $m(\pi)>0$ such that $V^{\widetilde{H}_{m(\pi)}}=0$ and $V^{\widetilde{H}_{m(\pi)+1}}\neq0$. Then we have 
$$\dim(V^{\widetilde{H}_{m(\pi)+1}})=1.$$

We know that there exist an integer $n\geqslant0
$ such that $V^{\widetilde{\Gamma}_{n}}\neq0$, where $\widetilde{\Gamma}_{n}$ is the the image in $G$ of the open compact subgroup of $GL(3,F)$ given by :
$$\Gamma_{n}=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{O}^{\times} & \mathcal{O}  & \mathcal{O} \\ \\
\mathcal{O}  & \mathcal{O}^{\times} & \mathcal{O} \\ \\ 
\mathcal{P}^{n} & \mathcal{P}^{n} & 1+\mathcal{P}^{n} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
(See Jacquet, Piatetski-Shapiro, Shalika, "Conducteur des représentations du groupe linéaire", Math. Ann. 256 (1981).)

Using this result, we can prove easily the proposition 1) since for every integer $n$ we have $\widetilde{H}_{2n}\subset \widetilde{\Gamma}_{n+1}$ and $\widetilde{H}_{2n+1}\subset \widetilde{\Gamma}_{n+2}$. But I don't have any idea to prove the proposition 2).

Comment: Your definition of $\Gamma_n$ is off; the top left $2 \times 2$ block is in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathcal{O})$, but this does not mean that the diagonal entries are in $\mathcal{O}^{\times}$.

Comment: Sorry, the 3-3 entry of matrix subgroup $\Gamma_{n}$ are in $\mathcal{O}^{\times}$.

Comment: Is there a reason why you expect 2) to hold? It seems to be much stronger than the result of JP-SS.

Comment: Sincerely, I'm not sure that proposition 2) is true. But the reason for which I believe that this result can be true is the work of Paul Broussous "Representations of PGL(2) of a local field and
harmonic forms on simplicial complexes".

Comment: In this work, Broussous prove that an irreducible cuspidal representation $\pi$ of PGL(2,F) appear as a sub-representation in the cohomology space $H_c^{1}(\widetilde{X}_k)$ with multiplicity one, where $k$ is the conductor of $\pi$ and $\widetilde{X}_k$ is the directed graph whose vertices are the geodesic paths of length k in the tree $X$ of PGL(2) and whose directed edges are the geodesic paths of length k+1. The subgroups $\widetilde{H}_n$ that I define are the stabilizers of certain kind of geodesic galleries of length $n$ in the Bruhat-Tits building of PGL(3,F).

Comment: I don't know much about that kind of thing. In any case, I would recommend reading "Old Forms on $\mathrm{GL}_n$" by Mark Reeder. Maybe his methods might help in your setting.